# SQL group by 3 columns with a special feature

Tags: sql, select, sqlite, group-by

I have a table that contains  name, color1, color2, color3 and other columns(SQLite):

```
CREATE TABLE data (name TEXT, lvlavailable INTEGER, lvlExtra TEXT,
color1 TEXT, color2 TEXT, color3 TEXT);
```

current data

```
INSERT INTO "someTable" VALUES ("name","Amarillo","NoColor","NoColor");
INSERT INTO "someTable" VALUES ("name","Amarillo","NoColor","NoColor");
INSERT INTO "someTable" VALUES ("name","Amarillo","Azul","NoColor");
INSERT INTO "someTable" VALUES ("name","Amarillo","Azul","NoColor");
INSERT INTO "someTable" VALUES ("name","Amarillo","Rojo","NoColor");
INSERT INTO "someTable" VALUES ("name","Amarillo","Rojo","NoColor");
INSERT INTO "someTable" VALUES ("name","Amarillo","Rojo","NoColor");
INSERT INTO "someTable" VALUES ("name","Amarillo","Rojo","NoColor");
INSERT INTO "someTable" VALUES ("name","Amarillo","Rojo","Verde");
INSERT INTO "someTable" VALUES ("name","Amarillo","Verde","NoColor");
INSERT INTO "someTable" VALUES ("name","Amarillo","Violeta","NoColor");
INSERT INTO "someTable" VALUES ("name","Azul","NoColor","NoColor");
INSERT INTO "someTable" VALUES ("name","Azul","NoColor","NoColor");
INSERT INTO "someTable" VALUES ("name","Azul","Amarillo","NoColor");
INSERT INTO "someTable" VALUES ("name","Azul","Amarillo","NoColor");
INSERT INTO "someTable" VALUES ("name","Azul","Amarillo","NoColor");
INSERT INTO "someTable" VALUES ("name","Azul","Amarillo","Rojo");
```

**Column name in this case is irrelevant**
**I know the inserts are not correct because of columns count, but I think you get the idea**

current select statement:

```
SELECT name, 
       color1, 
       CASE WHEN color2 = 'NoColor' THEN '' ELSE color2 END as color2, 
       CASE WHEN color3 = 'NoColor' THEN '' ELSE color3 END as color3 
 FROM someTable 
 GROUP BY color1,color2,color3,name
```

**case are for other purposes**

current outcome:

```
name    Amarillo        
name    Amarillo        
name    Amarillo    Azul    
name    Amarillo    Azul    
name    Amarillo    Rojo    
name    Amarillo    Rojo    
name    Amarillo    Rojo    
name    Amarillo    Rojo    
name    Amarillo    Rojo            Verde
name    Amarillo    Verde   
name    Amarillo    Violeta 
name    Azul        
name    Azul        
name    Azul            Amarillo    
name    Azul            Amarillo    
name    Azul            Amarillo    
name    Azul            Amarillo    Rojo
```

**name of colors are in spanish, sorry about that**

desired outcome:

```
name    Amarillo        
name    Amarillo        
name    Amarillo    Azul    
name    Amarillo    Azul
name    Azul            Amarillo    
name    Azul            Amarillo    
name    Azul            Amarillo
name    Azul            Amarillo    Rojo    
name    Amarillo    Rojo    
name    Amarillo    Rojo    
name    Amarillo    Rojo    
name    Amarillo    Rojo    
name    Amarillo    Rojo            Verde
name    Amarillo    Verde   
name    Amarillo    Violeta 
name    Azul        
name    Azul
```

notice that when it gets the group Amarillo,Azul,[empty], it will continue with Amarillo,Azul with independency of in wich column are each color, but I want to maintain original color column position, like shown and I don't want to create another column, just ordered.

So, what I want is to get those groups that have the same colors but in different order, together.

Is that possible?

Comment: please provide good table structure. this create quite confuse.

Comment: Would you please provide good result set , in your result set three column is there but is it all three color ? I think last two column is color column . if possible than please provide sample data and sample output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
select name, 
       color1, 
       case color2 when 'NoColor' then '' else color2 end as colour2, 
       case color3 when 'NoColor' then '' else color3 end as colour3
from data
order by
       case 
           when color2 = 'NoColor' then color1 
           when color3 = 'NoColor' then min(color1, color2)
           else min(color1,color2,color3)
       end,
       case
           when color2 = 'NoColor' then ''
           when color3 = 'NoColor' then max(color1, color2)
           else max(min(color1,color2),min(color1,color3),min(color2,color3))
       end,
       case color3
           when 'NoColor' then ''
           else max(color1,color2,color3)
       end
```

SQLFiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/014de/28).

Comment: Awesome job there!, It works perfectly, I would like to get all Amarillo,Azul,NoColor  and then all Azul,Amarillo,NoColor , not intercalated but is not necessary. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

If I've got it right:

```
select * from table1 
where 
 'red' in (color1,color2,color3) 
  and
 'blue' in (color1,color2,color3)
```

Ok here is group query for your data:

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/c6bb9/2)

```
select *

from someTable
group by 
(select 
  group_concat(c1)
  from
  (
  select c1 from
  (  
  select color1 as c1
  union all
  select color2 as c1
  union all  
  select color3 as c1 
  ) t2
  order by c1  
  ) t1
)
```

Comment: red description again, I updated it, but in summary I dont want to specify a color, i want it done automatically

Comment: Not getting the desired result, I will post a desired result in description, I thought I write it clear, but it seems i'm wrong